# KannelRoute message through 2 smsc

Tags: sms, gateway, kannel

I am new to this field. I have 2 smsc service provider connection. if i send 100 message 50 message should go through first service provider and rest 50 should go through 2nd service provider. is this possible? If so how to do it?

Thanks in advance

```
#1st service provider
group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = A
interface-version = 34
host = xxxxx  
port = xxxx
system-id = xxxxx
smsc-password = xxxx
system-type = "default"
address-range = ""
transceiver-mode = true
source-addr-ton = 1
source-addr-npi = 1
dest-addr-ton = 1
dest-addr-npi = 1
bind-addr-ton = 1
bind-addr-npi = 1
log-level = 0
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/xxxxx.log"

#2nd service provider
group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = B
interface-version = 34
host = xxxxx  
port = xxxx
system-id = xxxxx
smsc-password = xxxx
system-type = "default"
address-range = ""
transceiver-mode = true
source-addr-ton = 1
source-addr-npi = 1
dest-addr-ton = 1
dest-addr-npi = 1
bind-addr-ton = 1
bind-addr-npi = 1
log-level = 0
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/xxxxx.log"
```

Answer (score 1):

Kannel will load balance this for you if you set smsc-id to the same name for each route. If one SMSC goes down then all message will be sent via the alternative SMSC which is live. <strike>If both SMSC are live then Kannel will randomly pick one so you should achieve roughly 50/50 distribution (although not exactly 50/50)</strike>

-- edit--

sorry I checked and actually Kannel will send via the SMSC with the smallest queue so if you have low throughput of messages this will always be the first SMSC and you will not achieve anywhere near 50/50 distribution. This is under the code smsc2_rout() in gw/bb_smscconn.c of the kannel source code.